# PyCharm: DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined

Tags: python, django, environment-variables, pycharm

I am using PyCharm IDE and when I run any `file.py` I get this error:

> ..raise ImportError("Settings cannot be imported, because environment
>   variable %s is undefined." % ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE) ImportError:
>   Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable
>   DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.

How to configure `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable in PyCharm?

Comment: http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/quickstart/

Answer (score 31):

I had the same problem. The settings of my django support was empty:

[image: PyCharm project config]

Comment: Is this django support available only for professional edition and not the free  one ?

Comment: @SouravPrem yes Django support is only available in the professional edition of Pycharm

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem as well, and the fix in IntelliJ IDEA is not obvious (especially since there is no notification with a "fix-it" link for this problem).

You'll find you need to set Settings to your Django project's settings.py file in Project Structure > Modules > [your Django project's name] > Django.

[image: Now you know where to stick it.]

Answer (score 9):

You can go to the tool bar which shows a dropdown and select your project ->edit configuration. There in the Environment variable area enter DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE  mysite.settings and save .

Answer (score 8):

["Standalone Django scripts"](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/sep/22/standalone-django-scripts/)

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem and proposed solutions did not work.

I solved it by going in "File > Settings..."
Then search for "Django console" and add the following Environment variable: DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings

Answer (score 1):

for new commers, below is the additional info'.

where you can find the place to set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE in pycharm 2019.1 is:

config -> language and frameworks -> Django's right pain.

the column just below the django project root you can cite your config file path.

and the environment variables column you can set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE value.