# PyCharm: [08004] The server requested password-based authentication, but no password was provided

Tags: python, django, pycharm

Can't figure out why is `PyCharm` keeping raises this error:

[image]

I have set everything including **Django server** configuration and everything works - DB connection, remote host connection, django server etc.

Don't know if it's database problem. Connection works properly. The DB is remote on DigitalOcean droplet.

in **settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'our_db',
        'USER': 'django',
        'HOST': '<ip>',
        'PASSWORD': '<pwd>',
        'PORT': 5432,
        'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True,
    }
}
```

I have connection to remote **Ubuntu 16.04** where I use ssh key to authenticate.

Do you know where is the problem?

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988597/pycharm-django-settings-module-is-undefined

Comment: For the record: Pycharm provides a data source properties dialogue. If for some reason it is out of sync with settings, use the properties "test connection" button to fix the issue